# How to print the result of a system command in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following single line in my bash script:

```
echo "foo" | awk -F"=" '{char=system("echo $1 | cut -c1");}{print "this is the result: "$char;}' >> output.txt
```

I want to print the first letter of "foo" using awk, such that I would get:

```
this is the result: f
```

in my output file, but instead, I get:

```
this is the result: foo
```

What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not the way `system` command works inside `awk`.

***What's happening in OP's code:***

- You are giving a shell command in `system` which is good(for some cases) but there is a problem in this one that you should give it like `system("echo " $0" | cut -c1")` to get its first character AND you need NOT to have a variable etc to save its value and print it in `awk`.
- You are trying to save its result to a variable but it will not have its value(system command's value) but its status. It doesn't work like `shell` style in `awk` in here.
- So your variable named `char` will have `0` value(which is a success status from `system` command) and when you are printing `$char` it is printing whole line(because in `awk`: `print $0` means print whole line).

---

---

You could do this in a single `awk` by doing:

```
echo "foo" | awk '{print substr($0,1,1)}'
```

OR with GNU `awk` specifically:

```
echo "foo" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not using much of `awk`, same can be done with `printf`

```
$ echo "foo" | xargs printf "this is the result: %.1s\n"
this is the result: f
```

or, directly

```
$ printf "this is the result: %.1s\n" foo
this is the result: f
```